# Spock: mock mongodb bulk updates, fails on array comparison

Tags: mongodb, spock

I am trying to unit test some code which uses mongodb bulk updates.

The array of `UpdateOneModel` is constructed in a method using a java stream:

```
updates = myArray.stream().map(createBulkUpdate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

return userRepository.bulkUpdate(session, updates);
```

when trying to verify that in a spock test:

```
then:
1 * userRepository.bulkUpdate(session, [
    new UpdateOneModel<User>(new Document(), new Document())
])
```

I end up with the following error:

```
1: argument == expected
   |        |  |
   |        |  [UpdateOneModel{filter=Document{{}}, update=Document{{}}, options=UpdateOptions{upsert=false, bypassDocumentValidation=null, collation=null, arrayFilters=null}}] (java.util.ArrayList@5dc44d03)
   |        false
   [UpdateOneModel{filter=Document{{}}, update=Document{{}}, options=UpdateOptions{upsert=false, bypassDocumentValidation=null, collation=null, arrayFilters=null}}] (java.util.ArrayList@2dbc6d0a)
```

In both cases the string representation of the query is exactly the same. Just the address of the array seems to differ. I simplified the whole test to just make use of empty documents instead of the actual query in order to rule out any differences in the query itself during debugging.

Usually spock deals well with arrays and their content, so I am little surprised this fails.

Any ideas why this fails or how to make it work? Or better ideas to test something similar (ideally I wouldn't have to mock the database, but currently I do not see a good way how to make this happen)?

Comment: Not having seen more of your code - something like an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - and only quickly glancing at your snippet and the error log, one question immediately popped into my mind: How did you implement `UpdateOneModel.equals(Object)`? If Spock cannot check for equality, your condition will not work the way you expect. That would not be a Spock problem then. ;-)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I just checked and UpdateOneModel does not seem to implement `equals`. Btw, this class is from the mongo driver. Totally forgot about the `equals` method. Makes sense now.

Comment: Then either extend the class and define your own `equals` method (and make sure `Document` also has one) or you have to compare field values manually one by one, which would look quite ugly in a test. If you like I can convert my comments into an answer which you can then accept in order to close the question.